# Login Button crashes the application while connecting to web server

Tags: android, authentication, crash

can anyone please tell me whats wrong with my code. everytime i login the processing occurs for 3sec and then the app crashes.

This is my login.java code:

```
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.xxx.x.x/folder/login.php";

// JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // setup input fields
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    // setup buttons
    mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

    // register listeners
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.login:
        new AttemptLogin().execute();

        break;
    case R.id.register:
        Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();


    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                // save user data
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("username", username);
                edit.commit();

                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}
```

}

This is the logcat:

```
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591): Activity xxx.xx..Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{418aa1d0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.ss.appsec.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{418aa1d0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:218)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at com.ss.appsec.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:105)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at com.xx.xxx.Login.onClick(Login.java:83)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-11 23:41:27.361: E/WindowManager(5591):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 23:41:27.361: D/OpenGLRenderer(5591): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-11 23:41:27.362: W/Trace(5591): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your Intent in the post Execute after dismissing the progress dialog

Comment: should i remove the intent which i have mentioned in the doinBackground function and place it in postExecute?

Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("username", username);
                edit.commit();

                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

Comment: yes, You have a progress dialog which has to be dismissed before going to the next activity so add your intent after dismissing the progress dialog at post execute.

Comment: the app is still crashing :(
Now the error in logcat is:

03-12 00:44:23.874: E/JSON Parser(20011): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-12 00:44:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(20011): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
03-12 00:44:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(20011): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-12 00:44:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(20011):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)

Comment: Your first issue is resolved.. This issue is with the JSON parsing.. Kindly refere this tutorial for JSON parsing.. Your response string must be a JSON String so that it gets converted into JSON Object.    [link]http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/